# How to overlay vector grid to keep track of areas I have reviewed:ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vector-grid, overlay, tracking

I need to review large areas at the street level (in ArcMap) to make sure certain features are up to date. Is there a way to overlay a grid so I can "check off" areas I have already covered? I need the grid to show up in data view and layout view.

Comment: You could create a fishnet of polygons over your area of interest and attribute and display as appropriate.  Similarly you could create a new attribute in the data you are reviewing and attribute and display as appropriate.   https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm

Comment: Thank you, I will try the "Fishnet"